# How do I make this with template string?

Tags: javascript, template-strings

I have smth like this

```
const activeLang = 'pl'
 
const uniqueCategories = products.map((product) => {
      return product.category_pl
    })
```

How do I make this the same but with using template string. It should be smth like this

```
product.category`_${activeLang}
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I miss understood you question
any way check this solution

```js
const activeLang = 'pl'
const uniqueCategories = products.map((product) => {
      return product[`category_${activeLang}`]
    })
```

**Explanation** : using `[]` instead of . when we call a property of an object when the property has to be evaluated first.

for more check this answer : [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns array with 1 item ''undefined_pl"

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! :)

Comment: you are welcome .. please mak my answer as the correct answer (click the up arrow) .. thank you

Comment: I did, Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. So you can't see it but u got it